# CPU Intensive App Scaling

Tags: azure, cloud, scalability

I have FORTRAN algorithm which takes 15 - 20 seconds on one single core 2.4 GHZ machine with 100% cpu usage (on windows, but can try it on linux as well) . I need to execute it around 10,000 times. Every run will get .txt file as input and gives the .txt file as output. Once a batch of 10K runs are over , i would like to shut down everything till user triggers it again.

As per ruff calculation total time it can take if executed linearly is 
15 seconds * 10,000 Runs = 150000 sec (on single core) = 41.6 Hrs (on single 2.4 GHz core)

I would like to run it in extreme parallel mode. 
What can be the cloud based architecture options to achieve such a high scalability. I/P and O/P method of text file can be change but scalability is most important.

Answer (score 0):

Try Azure functions (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/functions/)
or webjobs (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/).

Similar architectures exist for AWS ([lamdas](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html)) and [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) as well but are all fairly new technologies.